# Zend post view delete/unlink

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi I have a zend view which echo's an  `<img src>` tag, I want to delete this image file after the page has been rendered, any ideas how I might do this?

Does the flow return to the controller after the view has been executed or does it just finish there? I tried to unlink the file after the echo but of course the html has not been rendered at that point.

So what I'm asking is there some sort of post view action I could use to unlink the file after the html has rendered?

Comment: One thing to remember is that just because you have rendered the page on the server and sent the response back to a waiting client, it doesn't mean that the client has actually received that response or that the user has actually seen it. A bad internet connection or client-side system freeze/crash could mean that the user never actually got to see the page you rendered. Under your scenario, once he refreshes the page, the image is gone (unless the image is actually generated during the request).

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thanks for clearing that up. The image is created as part of the request though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image will need to be there at least until the browser retrieves it, in order to be rendered. At that point, your server request has already finished.

A common way to remove files after the request has finished, is by using a "cleanup" cron task to be executed periodically.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yes I guess that would be acceptable, I would rather delete the file in the same request, if it is possible though..

Comment: If the file must be available to be downloaded/rendered in a browser, it's not possible to delete it during the same request, because the request is already over. You need to do it afterwards.

Comment: you might be able to create a plugin to do the task in the routestartup or predispatch of the next request.

Comment: OK I will look in to that. I just wondered whether there was some sort of post dispatch for Zend which might be able to do it.